# Visualisation of edges values on weight network

Tags: graphs-and-networks, neural-networks

I have a problem when I want to see
values of edges on my weight graph.

```
Z = Graph[{"A" -> "B","A" -> "B"}, EdgeWeight -> {5, 200}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

The both values displayed on my graph are 5 and not 5 and 200

Have you some idea why?

Comment: Your graph has 2 identical edges, and adding different weights to them was not supported until version 12.1.  In 12.1 you can use `{DirectedEdge["A", "B", 1], DirectedEdge["A", "B", 2]}` as your edge list and it works.

Comment: OK I don't know it was not supported...I try and it works Thanks @Jason B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In versions 12.1+, you can use [`EdgeTaggedGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeTaggedGraph.html):

```
EdgeTaggedGraph[{"A" -> "B", "A" -> "B"}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {5, 200}, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

[image]